# Specify update password when two emailids have same password

Tags: c#, passwords, webmethod

I want to update the password without making the user enter his username or emailid as the user will already be logged in.
So in the following code snippet of my webmethod, if i don't wanna use emailid=@emailid at where clause, 
where shud i add the code with the logic change password only at the emailid1 and not at emailid 2 if both emailids have same passwords? Thanks.

```
 string update = "update client set pwd=@newpass where pwd=@oldpass";
```

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: i just want user not to type the emailid again. As he can avail the chng password option only when he is once authenticated in my android app.

Comment: if you wont use the email in ur update clause someone could change the password of another account with the same pw accidently!?
also you dont want him to enter it again you can use it at the update clause!

Comment: foreg: if we wish to chng passwrd on fb, we dnt hv to enter our emailid. Thats wat i want.

Comment: In your case just use your primary key to identify the password to be replaced. if you really want all the users to have different passwords use a unique salt for each of them.

Comment: yes, if you are logged in your email is saved in a variable you can use at the update clause.

Comment: nono..i dnt want users to hv uniq passwords... i jst want that if they are already logged in, they dont have to write their emailids agn...thats it!!  is it possible and feasible???

Comment: @Vloxxity thats exactly what i am asking...can u guide me where can i get that variable thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is already logged in you should have the email in some variable.
And you can use this variable in your updatestring.
So the user dont need to type his email again.

Comment: but where can i get this variable? coz i am doing this in webmethods and applying it on android platform.  And on updating passwords, all the emailids having same passwords are changed.

Comment: you should set/create this variable as the userlogin.